# Emitter Resistor

Tags: transistors

Why is there a voltage drop of 2v across the C/E in the following circuit (XMM2)? I thought that a transistor behaves like a variable resistor, in that when you apply 0.7v across the base, it's like the resistance across the C/E goes to zero.

So I was expecting the 6v to be mostly dropped across R1 and R2.

Note : This is an amplifier circuit that I took from one of the books I am trying to learn electronics from. I was just seeing if I could explain the values I was seeing in the simulation.[image]

Comment: The variable resistor analogy works a lot better for MOSFETs than for BJTs.

Comment: I think the "variable resistor analogy" is wrong - as long as the BJT is concerned. Example: The current through the nodes C and E does NOT (or only very little) depend on the voltage across these two nodes. This is in sharp contrast to a resistor which you could imagine between these two nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The voltage across R2 rises when the collector current increases so it counteracts the base current.

Transistor dude (as seen in Win Hill & Horowitz's Art of Electronics) only sees the base current resulting from the voltage at the base **relative to the emitter**.

[image]

As an approximation (and if the divider on the base is low enough resistance, the transistor is high gain and is in the active region), the base current is close to zero, so Vb = 6V* R4/(R3+R4) or about 1.72V.

The base will load this (Ib= Ic/hFE), so it will actually be less. The emitter voltage will be about 0.7V less than the base (about 1V), so the emitter (and thus collector) currents will be around 1mA. Which means the collector voltage will be about 6V - 3V = 3V. Checking, the Vce is thus about 2V which is far from saturation. And, in this case, the numbers match the simulation quite well.

If you increased the base divider values by (say) 10:1 the estimate would not be as accurate because the base current would load the divider much more heavily.

Comment: Because the questioner thinks that "a transistor behaves like a variable resistor" - I am afraid that the shown picture could support this incorrect assumption....

Comment: @LvW it's not an invalid way of thinking about it. The variable resistor "transistor man" twiddles to maintain a constant current. It may help with intuitively understanding saturation, for example, which a dependent current source might not.

Comment: And....how can I derive the "constant current" feature from the picture? To me, it looks like a man who adjusts a resistor between C and E. And the current would be determined, of course, by the resistor value as well as the driving voltage between C and E. And such a view is misleading, is it not?

Comment: @LvW If you notice the bubbles above the "transistor man" head, he's adjusting the rheostat to get a given specific Ic as read on his ammeter. If the Vce changes he has to re-adjust the knob. Is it misleading? Maybe. Some people find it useful.

Comment: Do YOU find it useful? How could one know that the knob must be adjusted? More than that, such an adjustment is in contrast to practical use. For my opinion, even newbies should learn - from the beginning - how a BJT really works - of course, with simplifications but without "over-simplified" views. Is an exponential function too complicated for a guy who is interested in electronics?

Answer (score 0):

Although the variable resistance analogy is not really valid in this case (it is a BJT and that transistor is in the active region), the overarching issue would still remain. You have the transistor in a negative feedback configuration.

The current through the transistor circulates through R2, which reduces the transistor’s Vbe, which reduces the current through the transistor.

Answer (score 0):

Vbe is about 0.62V for this device model under these conditions as we can see from the base voltage (1.63V - 1.009V dropped across R2).

It is best to think of a bipolar junction transistor as a part which adjusts its emitter current to try to maintain ~0.6-0.7V (give or take) across the base/emitter junction (Actually this is very much 'lies to children', but don't worry about it yet). The base current is generally small compared to the collector current when operating in the linear region.

R2 provides negative feedback by developing a voltage across itself proportional to the current flowing in it, this voltage is clearly subtracted from the base voltage to give the difference Vbe which is what the transistor is trying to maintain.

We have 1.63V on the base, so the emitter will be at about 1V, which given R2 is 1k (This resistor is referred to as the emitter degeneration resistor in some of the literature) will give an emitter current of ~1mA. Beta is large so Ic ~= Ie, giving a collector current of about 1mA, which will develop ~3V across the 3k of R1, which leaves ~2V across the transistor itself.

Look mum, no Spice!

One of the nice things about this circuit is that its performance is substantially independent of device beta and also of small changes in Vbe (which is NOT stable with temperature), the feedback means that these things have little effect on either the bias point or circuit gain.

Comment: Dan - you have confused R2 and R3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about this diagram.

[image]

Noice how the bipolar becomes a (poor) constant current source, that current SET BY THE EMITTER RESISTOR in you circuit, once the Vce is 2 volts or more.

By the way, these lines are drawn with constant slope, and these lines intercept at some (imaginary negative ) voltage we call the EARLY voltage, or Vearly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the shown diagram can help to explain the role of the emitter resistor.
As one can see, the (unwanted) variation of the collector current caused by temperature changes can be kept much smaller (if compared with the case RE=0, vertical stabilization line).

Regarding uncertainties in the DC current gain B a similar effect can be observed (second figure: Variation in B causes only little changes in Ic if the slope of the line is small).

However, it is worth mentioning that in both cases it is the Voltage Vbe which determines the value of Ic - in accordance with Shockleys famous exponential reöationship Ic=f(Vbe).

[image]

Comment: Who is the author of this picture?

Comment: I have used the known relationships (as shown) and the exponential relation Ic=f(Vbe) from Shockley. Its original purpose was to show that - even in case of "current injection" - the collector current is determined and controlled by Vbe.